# Cannot find .so file error in tesseract ocr

Tags: android

This is my error while trying to implement tesseract ocr

> dlopen("/data/app-lib/app.my.myocr-12/liblept.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libjpgt.so" needed by "liblept.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libjpgt.so" not found

I am getting above error while trying to implement ocr using tesseract. I am using ndk 10 and have successfully built project. Can someone help me with my problem. Why am I getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this:
[github issue #150](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/issues/150)

Try adding this code to your app class:

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("jpgt");
    System.loadLibrary("pngt");
    System.loadLibrary("lept");
    System.loadLibrary("tess");
}
```